# The effect of high frequency AC current in a fresh corpse

Tags: electricity, biology

1. Given two AC currents of the same intensity, eg 20 mA, but different frequency, 60 Hz and 20MHz, which one would be more likely to reach the heart ?
2. I've read about the skin effect and how current tends to flow on the surface of a conductor. Does that apply to a dead human body at this particular context?
3. Would the low frequency penetrate the dead body and reach the heart and the high frequency be confined to the skin?

Comment: Low frequency AC is more likely to cause heart fibrillation than high frequency AC. I suggest you do some reading on the hazards of electricity on the body.

Comment: This would appear to be a question about [biology.se] rather than physics.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biology and human physiology.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on biology.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Ok let me fix it for you.

Comment: Maybe you and Mary Shelley should get together .... :) Seriously, though, I have read the skin effect you cite is not really relevant for frequencies as low as 60Hz.

Comment: The question is within the scope defined in the help center, specifically "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena". I wonder why people here are so picky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article is very good in describing the dangers of electricity, which I suggest you read. http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_3/4.html

To summarise the article, $20\text{ mA}$ for $60\text{ Hz}$ causes "severe pain, difficulty breathing, loss of voluntary muscle control", whereas $20\text{ mA}$ for $10\text{ kHz}$ is in between "threshold of perception, and painful", but voluntary muscle control is maintained.

Thus, in general, low frequency AC is more dangerous than high frequency AC (when everything else is kept constant).

Comment: You mean low frequency AC is more dangerous ?

Comment: @Zet My apologies, that is what I meant.